# Xpath always gives true

Tags: xpath

I have this case where i have a filter. This filter is stuck between 88 and 89.
The problem is the values i can have are 88,36 and 88,95.
My actualy case :

```
<div class="d-flex-inline">
<span>88,97</span>
<span>€/HT</span>
</div>
```

When I tried to give him this Xpath it always returns true either I give it a correct condition or not and always finds the element.

`/div[@class="prix"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1][boolean(number(text()) > 80) = false]` Returns true
`/div[@class="prix"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1][boolean(number(text()) < 80) = false]` Returns true

the xpath i want is one where i can give the initial filter values 88 and 89 i was planning to add the other condition if the bool worked but it didn't can you guys please assist me with this one.

FYI : When I tried

```
//div[@class="prix"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1][number(text()) = 88,97]
```

it didn't work and didn't find the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [XPath definition of a Number](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-Number) only allows `.` as the decimal separator, not `,` The [`number()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-number) uses that definition, and returns `NaN` ("not a number") for any string not in the expected format.

Since `NaN` can't be defined as either less than or greater than any specific value, the condition always returns false. (Your title says it always returns *true*, but that's because you're inverting it with `= false`).

You can use [the `translate()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) to replace the `,` with a `.` and then the number should parse correctly:

```
number(translate(text(), ",", "."))
```

In context:

```
/div[@class="prix"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1][boolean(number(translate(text(), ",", ".")) > 80) = false]
```

Incidentally, `boolean(foo) = false` can more simply be written with [the `not` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-not) as `not(boolean(foo))`, or just `not(foo)`:

```
/div[@class="prix"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1][not(number(translate(text(), ",", ".")) > 80)]
```

Comment: God bless u and thank u it works i found out about the , and . but was still searching for a way to make it work + it seems that i dont need the bool

Comment: Does it work or not?